# How can you get the final height on an element transitioning with css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If you have an element whose height is animating using a CSS transition, is there a way to use jQuery or pure Javascript to get its finished height before the transition completes?

Consider the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/qm6zz0kq/

```
<div id="test"></div>
<style>
    #test {
        width: 100px;
        height: 0;
        transition: height 2s ease-in-out;
        background: #F00;
    }
    #test.showing {
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var testElement = document.getElementById('test');
    setTimeout(function() {
        testElement.className = 'showing';
    }, 100);

    setInterval(function() {
        testElement.innerHTML = 'Height: ' + testElement.clientHeight;
    }, 100);

</script>
```

How could you modify the interval so it always generates "Height: 100"?

I've considered doing some kind of jQuery clone that doesn't have to transition and measuring its height but in this instance, the CSS is nested enough that I'd have to clone basically of the element's parents to make sure it's correct and that could be expensive.

Answer (score 2):

You can put another hidden div (`hidden-test`, as an example) that is the same as the div `test` and add to it the class `showing` right away (without timeout), then get its height, that will be the same.

Look here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/qm6zz0kq/1/

Comment: That's an interesting idea and I can see how it would work. It'd be nice if there was a way to do it directly with Javascript so I don't have to insert and track a bunch of extra elements but this is a clever fallback if that doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, to reduce the extra css #hidden-test and #hidden-test.showing, you could use classes instead and reuse some code, but I get your point.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the actual CSSRule, note though this would just get the value defined in the CSS. For instance if the `height` was specified as `70%` it would give `70%` and not the actual `px` height it would end up as, eg if parents height was 170px, it wouldn't give you the value of 70% of 170px. Also note this will not work if the stylesheet is include from a file `<link href="css.css">`

```js
var testElement = document.getElementById('test');
setTimeout(function() {
  testElement.className = 'showing';
}, 100);


setTimeout(function() {
  var rule = getRule("#test.showing");
  if(rule){
    testElement.innerHTML = 'Height: ' + rule.style.height;
  }
}, 100);


function getRule(selector) {
   var foundRule = null;
   [].slice.call(window.document.styleSheets)
     .filter(sheet=>sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules).forEach(sheet=>{
        foundRule = foundRule || [].slice.call(sheet.rules||sheet.cssRules)
                      .filter(rule=>rule.selectorText == selector);
     });
   if(foundRule && foundRule[0]) return foundRule[0];
}
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 2s ease-in-out;
  background: #F00;
}
#test.showing {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

You could also put in an element that is a clone. You do not have to also clone the parents like you mention in your question. You just have to insert the element into the same parent. This particular example uses `display:none` to hide the element, the returned value will not be a calculated value. Again like above if the parent's height is 400px and the height of the element is 75%, 100px will not be returned, 75% would be.

```
var clone = testElement.cloneNode();
//remove transition so we can get end height
clone.style.transition = "none";
//display:none so we do not have to see the temp element
clone.style.display = "none";
clone.classList.add("showing");

testElement.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
var endHeight = window.getComputedStyle(clone).height;
```

```js
var testElement = document.getElementById('test');
setTimeout(function() {
  testElement.className = 'showing';
}, 100);

//Clone the element
var clone = testElement.cloneNode();
//remove transition so we can get end height
clone.style.transition = "none";
//display:none so we do not have to see the temp element
clone.style.display = "none";
clone.classList.add("showing");

testElement.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
var endHeight = window.getComputedStyle(clone).height;
//Remove it as we dont need it anymore
clone.remove();

setTimeout(function() {
  testElement.innerHTML = 'Height: ' + endHeight;
}, 300);
```

```css
#parent {
  height:300px;
}
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 2s ease-in-out;
  background: #F00;
}
#test.showing {
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

If you want the actual calculated height you would need to change the clone to use a couple different stles.

`visibility:hidden` to hide it instead of `display:none`  as display will make it so we won't get a calculated value.

`position:absolute` to prevent it from modifying the parents dimensions

```
clone.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
clone.style.position = "absolute";
//needed to make sure element is contained by parent
parent.style.position = parent.style.position || "relative";

var endHeight = window.getComputedStyle(clone).height;
```

```js
var testElement = document.getElementById('test');
setTimeout(function() {
  testElement.className = 'showing';
}, 100);

//Clone the element
var clone = testElement.cloneNode();
//remove transition so we can get end height
clone.style.transition = "none";

clone.style.visibility = "hidden";
clone.style.position = "absolute";
clone.classList.add("showing");

var parent = testElement.parentNode;
parent.style.position = parent.style.position || "relative";
parent.appendChild(clone);

var endHeight = window.getComputedStyle(clone).height;
//Remove it as we dont need it anymore
clone.remove();

setTimeout(function() {
  testElement.innerHTML = 'Height: ' + endHeight;
}, 300);
```

```css
#parent {
  height:300px;
}
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 2s ease-in-out;
  background: #F00;
}
#test.showing {
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add an 'animationend' event listener to the element .

**Example :**

```
testElement.addEventListener('animationend' , showNewHeight);


showNewHeight function(){

// show new height ...do something after animation .
}
```

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp

hope this helps..

Comment: That would give me the height after the transition has completed but is there any way to find out what it will be after it finishes but before it actually has?

Comment: This wouldn't work anyway as OP is using a `transition` not an `animation`, you would need to use [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend)